# how to host UE4 shooter game across multiple pc in the same network

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am trying to build an FPS shooter game on top of the Shooter Game project that epic have in the learn tab, but I did stumble upon a problem when I tried to package it into a standalone game to test with some other people, they all use the same network as me by the way(meaning we connect to the same router, just to be clear). I am aiming for the LAN functionality where I host a game and then others can then join the session, but the problem is that it only works if both the instance that host a game and the instance that tries to connect to it, is in the same computer, otherwise it won't find a session at all. I have tried many things like port forwarding, DMZ zone, but still nothing works. It doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code though, as it works if all the instances is on the same computer(like I can successfully connect to the hosted session). I really don't know what else to try, I have searched for days, but it doesn't seem like people use that project at all so the answers is also limited, but I tried all of them and nothing seems to work.

I have also tried the dedicated server by the way, but also there I only got it to connect once the server a establish a game session, but after that time I tried alot of times to replicated it, but to no avail. Do someone have any idea what the problem might be here?

Comment: Have you inspected the client's log to see why the connection fails?

Comment: Firewall maybe?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be firewall, as I turned it off on all the computers, that was also what I thought at first too. I have also inspected the log for client, but my knowledge is limited though so I don't understand much of it, can I send you the logfile so you can see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind I figured it out, just wanted to share it if anyone else also have problem with this. Basically having something a virtual network like virtualbox can mess this create this problem as it can make it so the search packet will be broadcast to UDP, 255.255.255.255, port 14001 instead of the main network. In my case I just removed virtualbox(as I didn't use) and everything worked.